# How to shrink 2D complex shapes in themselves?

Tags: geometry, geometric-topology

Is there a robust method that can shrink 2D shapes in themselves like seen on the images? I am talking about more complex shapes than the ones on the image. Shapes that don't necessarily have such a clear segmentation (like an oval, and 2 squares).

[image]

One simple way would be to just run through all the points and add an offset in the direction of the normal, right? But, that would not exactly be the same, because you would have curves at the corners. At the corner, I would interpolate the normal on the left to the normal on the right.

So it would look something like this instead:

[image]

Comment: Are you asking for explanation on how do geometric transformations for resizing a composite [vector graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) image work?

Comment: Not specifically, but if there is a solution for that, possibly it would be applicable in my case too. Do composite vector graphics images resize as I show in the example image?

Comment: I checked in illustrator, and it seems like if I select a group of vector images, it will scale them to a point instead of each to its point. However, even if it would do a piece-wise scale, that would not work in my case, because I don't know my pieces.

Comment: How are you shapes stored (defined)? Can you include the representations of the given example shapes in such a way?

Comment: It's a graph. List of points in clockwise order.

Answer (score 0):

Methods related to this problem:

- [Medial Axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_axis#:%7E:text=The%20medial%20axis%20of%20an,known%20as%20the%20cut%20locus.)
- [Straight skeleton](https://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/open/skeleton.html)